# Clean install of Lion

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, leopard

I have a 1st generation MacBook Air running Leopard 10.5.8. Recently it's not working very smoothly anymore. I've my Lion 10.7.4 retail DVD with me. When I boot up to the Lion CD, it shows that I can't update from the current OS.

So if I use Disk Utility to format the hard drive, then will the installation install a new, clean Lion to my hard drive?

Comment: There was never a Lion retail DVD. Either you burned your own (which is legal) or it's the retail USB disk.

Comment: I got the disk image from my friend and the file name has "retail" so that just put the "Retail" word in my text.

Comment: OK. It's probably a copy of the retail USB disk. It should work in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Apple OS X Lion](https://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html) website:

> General requirements: 
>   Mac computer with an Intel Core 2 Duo, Core i3, Core i5, Core i7, or Xeon processor

The MacBook Air 1st gen has a Core 2 Duo processor. [source](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air)

So it should work.

Comment: What you didn't cover in your answer: the reason you can't install Lion now is that it will only upgrade Snow Leopard. A clean install should, indeed, work.

Comment: I'm new to Mac and I only upgrade Snow Leopard to Lion only. When I boot up the same Lion disk and click on install Lion. It's show the Local HD and said cannot upgrade The things I wonder that this disk is support clean install also or just upgrade process?

Comment: @NamPhung All OS X install media should support both clean install and upgrade.